# Do you add "在“ before saying "___年“？

Tags: vocabulary

I'm trying to remember what is the proper way to use time. Do we ever add 在 before a year when writing? Or do we generally not add it? Here's an example sentence that I wrote. Would you add 在？

> 在2006年， 当刘强东正在寻求资金时， 中国的物流系统非常糟糕。

Comment: Either is grammatical (but in your case, omitting 在 can avoid the repetition of this character as "正在" is nearby – it would sound slightly better to some ears). And ... if you use Chinese punctuation, you shouldn't put a space after it because the space is already considered/contained in the punctuation (if the font is well designed). `2006年，当刘强东正在寻求资金时，中国的物流系统非常糟糕。` is perfect.

Comment: this can be checked by feeding "在２０００年" to jukuu e.g., there find 100 examples (the max number)

Answer (score 4):

You sentence is correct with or without the 在. Using 在 will put a bit more emphasis on the year, while leaving off 在 will put a bit more emphasis on the action. Also, if you're listing years, you would not use 在:

2006年，中国的物流系统非常糟糕。2008年，仍然糟糕